# C#: How to get zoom value back from the WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, zooming

I succesfully set zoom value to the my WebBrowser member like below:

```
ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref pvaIn, null);
```

What I'm trying to do is get back updated value via:

```
object pvaOut;
ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, null, pvaOut);
```

Got an exception during that attempt.
According to MSDN, OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM is used only for setting zoom value.
So the question is how to get value which was set back?

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive the value which is actually set to the zoom value by using the pvaOut parameter.

```
ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref pvaIn, ref pvaOut);
```

pvaOut receive the corrected zoom level value if pvaIn was not in range.